# How do I determine if a table is created?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access 2010 VBA code I may or may not create a table depending on results of a DoCmd.OpenQuery.  I can check the record count which causes an "ON ERROR" branch that I can set, but I was looking for a neater way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you mark HansUp's answer as accepted one by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer, that may help you in the future as it will show that you appreciate other people's time and efforts to solve your technical problems

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're asking.

You can use DCount() to determine the number of rows returned by a SELECT query.

```
Debug.Print DCount("*","YourQueryName")
```

If instead the issue is determining whether a table exists, you can check for the table name in the TableDefs collection.  This statement will return the table's name if it exists, or throw a trappable error if it doesn't exist.

```
Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("YourTableName").Name
```

If you want to avoid trapping an error you could use a For ... Next loop to iterate through the TableDefs collection and break out of the For loop if you find the name.

Alternatively you could use a SELECT query to look for the table name in the MSysObjects system table.

```
SELECT MSysObjects.[Name], MSysObjects.[Type]
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE
    (((MSysObjects.[Name])="YourTableName")
    AND ((MSysObjects.[Type])=1));
```

That query would check for the table name as native Access table in the current database.  If you might have a linked table from another Access database (Type=4) or an ODBC data source (Type=6) by that name, change the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT MSysObjects.[Name], MSysObjects.[Type]
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE
    (((MSysObjects.[Name])="YourTableName")
    AND ((MSysObjects.[Type]) In (1, 4, 6)));
```

If you query MSysObjects, make sure you don't change any values.  Also I've heard some Access 2007 users encounter read permission errors for MSysObjects.  You could avoid the first problem by using DCount() instead of a query.

```
Debug.Print DCount("*","MSysObjects","[Name]='YourTableName' AND [Type] In (1, 4, 6)")
```

Comment: To HansUp: Thank you.  The issue was whether the table existed and your solutions will work for me.  I appreciate.